# how to set select dropdown back to its title attribute using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what I am trying to do is I have dropdown with title attribute and some options like below:

```
<select class="form-control kt-selectpicker" id='from_1_0' name='from_1_0'  title="From">   
                                                <option selected value="7">7 am</option>
                                                <option  value="8">8 am</option>
                                                <option  value="9">9 am</option>
                                                <option  value="10">10 am</option>
                                                <option  value="11">11 am</option>
                                                <option  value="12">12 pm</option>
                                            </select>
```

Now if user change the above dropdown to select any time for example they have selected option to set time 8am like below output:

[image]

Once this done then I have reset button where I am trying to again add the code to again set back my dropdown to its orignal state like below:

[image]

So not sure how I can set back my select dropdown option to set the title in option?

I tried some code like below:

```
//alert("J= "+j+" here");
                    //$("#from_1_"+j).attr('title','From');
                    //var test = $("#from_1_"+j).text();
                    //console.log(test);
                    //$("#from_1_"+j).selectpicker('refresh');
                    //$("#to_1_"+j).attr('title','To');
                    $("#from_1_"+j).find("option:selected").attr("title","From");
```

but none of the above code is helpful me to set title of select dropdown to "from" and remove the 8am as selected option.

please help?

Comment: Do you know what `title` attribute is?

Comment: No I wanted to set the title of select dropdown again after user change the option to 8am...@RoboRobok

Comment: But it's not the `title` attribute that makes the `From` label. The `title` attribute only displays a hint when you hover your mouse over the dropdown. You need a separate `From` option serving as a default option, which could have an empty `value`. Then, you could reset your dropdown with `dropdown.value = ''`.

Comment: @RoboRobok I know I can do this way to set like <option value="">from</option> However, I don't want to do that and wanted to set the title back like refreshing the select dropdown.

Comment: Not through `title`. You can set `.text('From')` on that option if you like.

Comment: not really I wanted to set the text for selected option by user because if I do so then user may not get again 8am option as it's overwritten by From keyword @RoboRobok

Comment: I don't get it what you wanna do. That's not how people use the dropdowns, is it? Why you wanna hide the value? Isn't it better to put label before the dropdown, so From was always there?

Answer (score 1):

Before you can select the value you want you need to have option with the title you want, so it work like empty value:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('select').val(null);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control kt-selectpicker" id='from_1_0' name='from_1_0'  title="From"> 
    <option value>From</option>
    <option selected value="7">7 am</option>
    <option  value="8">8 am</option>
    <option  value="9">9 am</option>
    <option  value="10">10 am</option>
    <option  value="11">11 am</option>
    <option  value="12">12 pm</option>
</select>
<button>reset</button>
```

And if you can't have that option you can add it dynamically:

```js
var select = $('select');
var empty = select.attr('title');
select.prepend('<option value>' + empty + '</option>');

$('button').click(function() {
  $('select').val(null);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control kt-selectpicker" id='from_1_0' name='from_1_0'  title="From">
    <option selected value="7">7 am</option>
    <option  value="8">8 am</option>
    <option  value="9">9 am</option>
    <option  value="10">10 am</option>
    <option  value="11">11 am</option>
    <option  value="12">12 pm</option>
</select>
<button>reset</button>
```

And if you want those From to be default value just add select to that option either static of dynamic.